# how to retrive data from mysql using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how use this data in jquery ajax

set data into data tables.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM callers';

$result = mysql_query($sql);


$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$row_data = array(
'twilio_no' => $row['twilio_no'], 
'phone_no' => $row['phone_no'],
'datetime' => $row['datetime'],
'carrier' => $row['carrier'],
'country' => $row['country'],
'country_zip' => $row['country_zip'],
'city' => $row['city'],
'state' => $row['state'],
'recording' => $row['recording']
);
array_push($data, $row_data);
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I have try to implement but give error like data tables incorrect  parameter(0).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var url = 'acall.php';
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, data) {
       $('#tablebody').append('<tr>');
   $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.twilio_no+'</td>');
   $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.phone_no+'</td>');
   $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.datetime+'</td>');
   $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.carrier+'</td>');
 $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.country+'</td>');
 $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.country_zip+'</td>');
 $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.city+'</td>');
 $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.state+'</td>');
 $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.recording+'</td>');
   $('#tablebody').append('</tr>');
  });

  });
                });
             });

</script>
```

this code use for append data into data tables but its not working and give data table warning

Comment: `I have try to implement ...` Please show us the code that you've already written.

Comment: You have one too much `});` in your javascript code. Indent your code properly and you should see that easily.

Comment: ohh yes. thanks @MrUpsidown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,

    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }

});
```

url 'example.php' is your php file path.

data 'formData' is your form data.